# Array in swipe cards Getting first element

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, string

I have created a array in my controller. Based on that JSON array my cards[tinderswipecards/cwRichard] are created . Now I want if I remove a card I want to get the data of card Shown to display somewhere in my viewController something like this[image: like this]

My cards coming from DraggableBackgroundView Class and i m implementing this in my own viewController

```
_peopleNearBypeopleList = [NSMutableArray new];



 [dataArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop)
                              {

   PeopleNearByIndividualModel * model = [PeopleNearByIndividualModel new];
                     NSDictionary *dicData = obj;
         model.senderId = [[dicData objectForKey:USER_ID] integerValue];
         model.displayName = [[dicData objectForKey:DISPLAY_NAME] uppercaseString];
         model.userImage = [dicData objectForKey:@"image"];
         [self.peopleNearBypeopleList addObject:model];

      NSLog(@"%@",_peopleNearBypeopleList);

      if (idx == [dataArray count] - 1) {

         [self createInvitationViews];
         }
```

and the strings to be created like

```
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < [_peopleNearBypeopleList count]; i++) {


  PeopleNearByIndividualModel * model = [_peopleNearBypeopleList objectAtIndex:i];




  NSString *nameString = @"ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO INVITE ";



  nameString = [nameString stringByAppendingString:model.displayName];
    NSLog(@"%@", nameString);

    _textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:17.0f];
    _textView.text = nameString;

}
```

again and it is calling the first Object.how can i acheive this

this is my draggableViewBackground Class

```
      //%%% loads all the cards and puts the first x in the "loaded cards" array
     -(void)loadCards:(NSArray*)array
     {

     exampleCardLabels = array;


     if([exampleCardLabels count] > 0) {
     NSInteger numLoadedCardsCap =(([exampleCardLabels count] > MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)?MAX_BUFFER_SIZE:[exampleCardLabels count]);
     //%%% if the buffer size is greater than the data size, there will be an array error, so this makes sure that doesn't happen



       //%%% loops through the exampleCardsLabels array to create a card for each label.  This should be customized by removing "exampleCardLabels" with your own array of data
          for (int i = 0; i<[exampleCardLabels count]; i++) {
              MG_DraggableVIew* newCard = [self  createDraggableViewWithDataAtIndex:i];
            [allCards addObject:newCard];

            if (i<numLoadedCardsCap) {
            //%%% adds a small number of cards to be loaded
            [loadedCards addObject:newCard];
        }
    }



           //%%% displays the small number of loaded cards dictated by MAX_BUFFER_SIZE so that not all the cards
          // are showing at once and clogging a ton of data
           for (int i = 0; i<[loadedCards count]; i++) {
            if (i>0) {
            [self insertSubview:[loadedCards objectAtIndex:i] belowSubview:    [loadedCards objectAtIndex:i-1]];
        } else {
            [self addSubview:[loadedCards objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
         cardsLoadedIndex++; //%%% we loaded a card into loaded cards, so we have to increment
         }
      } 
//      }
     }

    #warning include own action here!
   //%%% action called when the card goes to the left.
   // This should be customized with your own action
   -(void)cardSwipedLeft:(UIView *)card;
  {
//do whatever you want with the card that was swiped
//    DraggableView *c = (DraggableView *)card;

     [loadedCards removeObjectAtIndex:0]; //%%% card was swiped, so it's no  longer a "loaded card"

    if (cardsLoadedIndex < [allCards count]) { //%%% if we haven't reached the end of all cards, put another into the loaded cards
    [loadedCards addObject:[allCards objectAtIndex:cardsLoadedIndex]];
    cardsLoadedIndex++;//%%% loaded a card, so have to increment count
    [self insertSubview:[loadedCards objectAtIndex:(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE-1)] belowSubview:[loadedCards objectAtIndex:(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE-2)]];
}





          }

         #warning include own action here!
      //%%% action called when the card goes to the right.
      // This should be customized with your own action
      -(void)cardSwipedRight:(UIView *)card
     {
     //do whatever you want with the card that was swiped
      //    DraggableView *c = (DraggableView *)card;

        [loadedCards removeObjectAtIndex:0]; //%%% card was swiped, so it's no longer a "loaded card"

        if (cardsLoadedIndex < [allCards count]) { //%%% if we haven't reached the end of all cards, put another into the loaded cards
    [loadedCards addObject:[allCards objectAtIndex:cardsLoadedIndex]];
    cardsLoadedIndex++;//%%% loaded a card, so have to increment count
    [self insertSubview:[loadedCards objectAtIndex:(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE-1)] belowSubview:[loadedCards objectAtIndex:(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE-2)]];
}







           }

        //%%% when you hit the right button, this is called and substitutes the swipe
        -(void)swipeRight
     {
 MG_DraggableVIew *dragView = [loadedCards firstObject];
 dragView.overlayView.mode = GGOverlayViewModeRight;
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
     dragView.overlayView.alpha = 1;
 }];
 [dragView rightClickAction];



  }

       //%%% when you hit the left button, this is called and substitutes the swipe
     -(void)swipeLeft
    {
  MG_DraggableVIew *dragView = [loadedCards firstObject];
  dragView.overlayView.mode = GGOverlayViewModeLeft;
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    dragView.overlayView.alpha = 1;
  }];
   [dragView leftClickAction];
   }
```

Comment: You will have to access the array element by using index of the view which you are removing by dragging it.

Comment: can you explain  more.?

Comment: I think you are not referring  the data by using index. I mean if you have array of data for a card, then 1st card will have data at index 0 in your data array. So now when you are dragging your card you should get that index of card and fetch the exact data from the data array, which I think is not done in your code anywhere.

Comment: can you provide some code ,.?

Comment: I will suggest you to maintain a dictionary for card number or id (which will be unique for each card) and its data. So whenever you are removing card simply access data from dictionary by its key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can post a `NSNotification` inside `-(void)cardSwipedLeft:(UIView *)card` & `-(void)cardSwipedRight:(UIView *)card` method in `DraggableViewBackground`.

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index] forKey:@"someKey"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```

Here index is your card index. To set the index, you can declare a `int` property named index. Set initial value value of index like `index=0;` in `initwithframe` method.

then, increase the value of index when you swipe a card.

set `index++;` inside `-(void)cardSwipedLeft:(UIView *)card` & `-(void)cardSwipedRight:(UIView *)card` method in `DraggableViewBackground`.

Listen for this notification in your view controller. To achieve that add in the view controller's method in `viewDidLoad` by this line:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:)
                                                 name:@"TestNotification"
                                               object:nil];
```

implement this selector method in your viewcontroller-

```
- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"]){
         NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");
        NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
        int myObject = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"someKey"]integerValue];
        NSLog(@"index: %d", myObject);
    }

}
```

on `receiveTestNotification` method you get card index. then you can get your data from your array by index.

Comment: how can i set index to my card index?

Comment: yeah thanx buddy need to ask you more can you come on chat .plz send me link

Comment: @Dheeraj You can join with me on ..http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130131/room-for-dipankar-das-and-dheeraj

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it will be better for you if you maintain a `dictionary` for cards and their `data`.

You can create a dictionary with keys as card ids/card numbers and values as their data (description.)

So whenever you are removing card, simply fetch its `data` from `dictionary`.

Lets say `cardsDictionary` is your `dictionary` like this :

```
cardsDictionary = @{@"card1_id":@"card1_data"......@"cardn_id":@"cardn_data"};
```

Then on removing a card you can do like this:

```
card_data = cardsDictionary[@"card_id"];
```